# jquery val() chopping off result after first space

Tags: jquery

When I call:

```
var status = $('#status').val();
```

And the value is set to something with a space (in this case "Please Select..."), the status variable comes back with "Please", chopping off everything after the first space.

After further testing, I see this appears to only happen with Combo Boxes

Here's the markup:

```
<select name = "status" id="status" class="wide_field">
        <?php
            populate_list("statuses.txt");
        ?>
    </select>
```

And the php

```
            function populate_list($list_file)
            {
            echo "<option value=Please Select...>Please Select...</option>";
                $file = file($list_file,$file);
                for($i=0;$i<count($file);$i++)
                {
                    echo "<option value=".$file[$i].">".$file[$i]."</option>";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Might be something else with the surrounding code.. could you please give us some context to the line of code you posted already? For example what element is the `#status` selector referencing?

Comment: We need more code. Can we see your markup?

Comment: And I think I see the problem...

Comment: Place quotes around your values.

Answer (score 4):

Place quotes around your values.

Ex: `echo "<option value=\"Please Select...\">Please Select...</option>";`

Comment: That did it - and now I feel dumb. Amazing how eyes can miss things like that even with syntax highlighting.